# I would like to edit my answer to replace the example, in order respond to a critique in the comments

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

I would like to make [this edit](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/95559/2), but it was [rolled back](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/95559/3).

The original example application of judicial notice that I have included in the answer is attracting comments that critique the judge's math. The precise math used was not the point of the example.

If I were to replace the example with an accurate example, it would render the comments and subsequent discussion in the comments unnecessary, so I would like to make an edit to use an example without any errors that distract from the point I want to communicate.

May I make [this edit](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/95559/2)?

Answer (score 1):

### Don’t rewrite history

The judicial example includes a mathematical error - that’s interesting, people have commented on it. It is not obviously distractive, indeed it is in itself illustrative of the difference between a legal fact and a scientific fact.

If you want to *add* another example- fine. If you want to edit the question to highlight that the judge made a mathematical error and that is now judicially correct - even better.

Comment: When you press submit your answers (or questions) belong to Stack Exchange.